# Why my program writes file over and over instead of adding data?

Tags: java, newline, writer

Why my program writes file over and over instead of adding data?

I want to write in file but it always delete previous and write new...

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("koce_podatki.txt", true));
    //WRITES 1 LINE TO FILE AND CHANGES LINE
    writer.write(temp);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("s_koce.txt", true));
    //WRITES 1 LINE TO FILE AND CHANGES LINE
    writer.write(ime.getText());
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: *"I want to write in file but it always delete previous and write new..."* I don't believe it does. I think there's something *else* going on.

Comment: And sure enough, it doesn't: http://pastie.org/5869004 Run that more than once, giving it two args each time (the first is written to koce_podatki.txt, the second to s_koce.txt), and the new data is *appended*, not overwritten. The problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used thics, and it worked:

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("koce_podatki.txt", true)));
    out.println(temp);
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //oh noes!
}
```

Comment: Your other code works too.

Comment: I dont knew what but this thing worked out as well